# Securely register a client in server using AES an RSA

Tags: rsa, aes, public-key

I've designed the following protocol to send the client's public key to the server. Initially, the client knows server's public key, but the server does not know the client's public key.

1. client draws a random AES key
2. client enciphers the AES key using the server's RSA public key and sends the result
3. server receives this and deciphers it using the server's RSA private key
4. server generates userID and stores it with the client's public key for later use
5. server creates message with userID, signs it with its private key, enciphers it using the AES key and sends it to the client
6. client deciphers it using the AES key, validates origin using server's public key and stores userID.

What can go wrong? Can replay attacks cause any damage? What about Eve-in-the-middle attacks?

Comment: What do you actually do when writing "AES encrypts X", what padding do you (plan to) use for RSA (encryption + signature)? AND the most important question: Why don't you simply use TLS (unilaterally authenticated in the first run, with client authentication starting at the second run after registering the public key)?

Comment: TLS RFC is 100+ pages long for a reason.